# python auto indent problem

Tags: indentation, python

I'm using Emacs 24.4. When writing Python code, Emacs behaves strangely with respect to indentation.

For example:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
for i in range(10)
```

When I input `:`, Emacs adds a needless indent at the beginning of the third line. This is quite strange, is this a bug?

Comment: Can you add your .emacs init file

Comment: @VivianMaya This has nothing to do with config files, `emacs -Q` still has this problem

Comment: my friend sometimes Indentation might cross something, I had problem like this and that was about crossing definition. If you sure its nothing to do with, then I clearly don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is caused by `electric-indent-mode`, which is enabled by default in
Emacs 24.4. You can turn it off with

```
(electric-indent-mode -1)
```

---

If you don't want to disable electric indent mode entirely but want to
stop the colon from activating electric indent mode in Python mode, then
you could remove the colon character from `electric-indent-chars`, which
Python mode gives a local value.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq electric-indent-chars (delq ?: electric-indent-chars))))
```

Comment: What I'd really like to see is: when the indent I've put is legal Python, LEAVE IT ALONE. electric-indent-mode mindlessly guesses what I want when I've already told it...

Comment: And lo, these many years later, it's still broken.

Comment: And lo, two more years have passed.