# Return heavily indents previous line

Tags: indentation

If I'm editing certain filetypes then sometimes when I hit return at the end of a line the cursor will move to the next line and the previous line will suddenly be heavily indented.

This behavior seems to happen in a few different filetypes under various conditions but I can reliably reproduce this in an .el file on a comment line.

For example, with the cursor indicated by `_`, if I'm on a line that reads

```
; word_
```

and then I press return I get the following.

```
                            ; word
_
```

What's going on? I commented out all tabbing related settings from my configuration files and I still get this behavior.

Comment: a single semicolon conventionally indicates a margin comment or an annotation.  For full line comments a double-semicolon is used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `electric-indent-mode`. If you disable it, the behavior you describe will go away.

A similar question has been asked on here [before](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3322/504). The [accepted answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3338/504) describes how to disable electric indentation for specific characters. Adapting the code to your specific situation, we get:

```el
(defun electric-indent-mode-configure ()
  "Delete newline (?\n) from `electric-indent-chars'."
  (setq electric-indent-chars (delq 10 electric-indent-chars)))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'electric-indent-mode-configure)
```

With this in place, you can have `electric-indent-mode` turned on *without* getting the behavior you describe.

Comment: Is there a way to get electric indentation only for a new line and only immediately after hitting return?

Comment: @Praxeolitic I'm not sure what you mean, can you give a concrete example of the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Found it! I was looking for the behavior of `electric-indent-just-newline`. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3217/2139